# How do i get the response from an @Output() onSuccess: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(); to a function in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component I created

```
    <component-button [customStyle]="{'font-size.px':14, 'color' : 'green', 'background-color' : 
     'coral'}"
      [(onSuccess)="itsDone(response)"> Make request

</component-button>
```

the `onSuccess` emitter returns a Json response, but I have a problem getting the json response as a parameter in my itsDone() function.

```
itsDone(json) {
console.log('done successful', json);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How and when are you using your event emitter?

In your child component, you should do:

```js
    this.onSucess.emit(someJsonValue);
```

And then catch it just like you're doing, although the event has to be named $event, since it's how the EventEmitter works:

```html
    <component-button [customStyle]="{'font-size.px':14, 'color' : 'green', 'background-color' : 
         'coral'}"
          (onSuccess)="itsDone($event)"> Make request

    </component-button>
```

(Notice how I deleted the square bracket before the (onSucess), it's a typo)